# Why is a C++ reference to a temporary variable in the constructor allowed?

Tags: c++, oop

In the code example below, isn't the reference to the `bar` variable invalid, as the variable is local? Isn't the variable `bar` deleted after the constructor returns? What happens to the reference after that?

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int bar) : bar_(bar)
    {
    }

    int &bar_;
};

Foo foo{456};

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo.bar_ << std::endl;
    // output: 456
    return 0;
}
```

(This code compiles without errors or warnings with `g++ -Wall -Wextra`)

Comment: Why should the variable be temporary? It is globally assigned

Comment: @RoQuOTriX constructor takes `bar` by value

Comment: This isn't allowed. clang does warn about this.

Comment: g++ does not warn about that undefined behavior, even with `-Wextra -pedantic -Wall`

Comment: @idclev463035818 An reference in a class like this doesnt't make sense either. The compiler does, what the (dumb) programmer wants to do...

Comment: C++ is not a nanny language.  It doesn't protect you very much from making mistakes.  It gives you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: In the words of Bjarne, the creator of C++: "Restricting language features with the intent of eliminating programmer errors is at best dangerous."

Comment: clang spots it (not so gcc and MSVC) live - https://godbolt.org/z/g_jWGK

Comment: all references are not silentely accepted fortunately, for instance `int & foo(int bar) { return bar; }` produces the g++ warning `warning: reference to local variable ‘bar’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]`

Comment: @Eljay Impressive kind of rope!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that your analysis is basically correct. `bar_` will be a dangling reference, because its referent will be destroyed when the ctor returns.

Some compilers (notably clang) will warn you about this:

```
foo.cpp:6:25: warning: binding reference member 'bar_' to stack allocated
      parameter 'bar' [-Wdangling-field]
    Foo(int bar) : bar_(bar)
                        ^~~
foo.cpp:10:10: note: reference member declared here
    int &bar_;
         ^
1 warning generated.
```

My personal advice is to install and regularly use at least a couple of different compilers, and enable (virtually?) all warnings on every one to help catch problems like this. Lint-like tools such as cppcheck are helpful as well.

Comment: ew why does it use "stack allocated" terminology :(

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I suppose clang is allowed to do that because it knows it uses a stack :). Still weird though.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: because you haven't submitted a pull request with improved wording (yet)? ;-)

Comment: @JerryCoffin Indeed!

Comment: @Kevin Touché ;) Yeah just seems like a wording choice that makes things worse overall but maybe that's just me

Comment: @bloody The point is that that is an implementation detail, that in general may not hold (when talking about local variables in particular) so, in my experience, some wise C++ professionals prefer to teach about _automatic storage duration_ and _dynamic storage duration_ and _static storage duration_ so that we remain within the abstractions defined by C++ rather than making potentially false claims about implementation details. It's difficult because the "old" terms are very widespread. The wording of this diagnostic undermines the effort. I appreciate that not everybody's on board with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Compilation fails if the constructor has a reference as argument, and I was expecting it to fail in this case also. Guess I have to be more careful than I thought with references!

Comment: @Brun There are rules about what you can bind a reference to (e.g. not an rvalue, like `123`); so, it's much easier to get that right, than the possibility of dangling a reference that you _did_ manage to obtain!

Comment: @bloody No, certainly not - the notion of "optimisations" (don't get me started on that term) means there's no reason to assume some local variable is on any "stack". It could be stuck directly in a register, baked into your program's instructions, elided entirely, ... And this isn't just theoretical. C++ is way more abstract than many people for some reason realise. Possibly because it's only really in the last 20(?) years or so that compilers have been smart enough to really make use of that to produce smart, lean code.

Comment: (I imagine that early implementations produced code that, procedurally, looked more like the sequence of instructions given in your source code, rather than a smart, lean program that shared the described semantics. Some people would call this "being worse at optimising" but I religiously take a higher-level view and recommend others do the same!)

Answer (score 1):

It's "allowed" as much as any dangling reference: *it isn't*, and your program has undefined behaviour, and this is generally not diagnosed. It is your responsibility not to do it!

Some static analysers can help, including those that form part of toolchains. e.g. Clang does warn about this.

Comment: By the way, "temporary variable" is a specific (other) thing in C++ so you'd be better off not using that term to describe local variables and function arguments.

Comment: In this case the reference is dangled in the same scope that is created so it is a clear cut case the compiler could detect easily. And it does this for rvalues `warning: a temporary bound to ‘foo::s’ only persists until the constructor exits [-Wextra]` so why not for lvalues? It would be a useful warning because it picks up the case of a typo in the parameter causing you to pass in a copied object when you meant to pass in the reference.